# Jenkins Pipelines: Re-use workspace when loading an external Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: workspace, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following use case:

1. Checkout/pull a certain Git revision, using written pipeline script
   (I need this because I retrieve the revision dynamically)
2. From that revision, load a Jenkins-pipeline-file, located among the previously checked out files
3. This file would rely on files from the same checked out revision
   (thus, from the **same** workspace)

Problem: The loaded Jenkins-pipeline-file gets executed in a **new** workspace. But it is empty. I need that file to get executed in the **same old** workspace.

I thought, perhaps it's because of surrounding `node`, because the `node` keyword creates workspaces, as mentioned in the docs. But when I tried to load it *outside* the `node`, Jenkins disallowed this because of "leaving the sandbox".

Note: the jenkins-pipeline-file is found and really gets executed. The problem is **during** the execution.

---

**Please look at the example code:**

***Inlined pipeline script***

```
node('master') {
  def latestBuildableRevision = readFile '/my/LATEST-BUILDABLE-REVISION.txt'

  checkout poll:false,
   scm:[$class:'GitSCM', branches:[[name:latestBuildableRevision]],
   doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations:false,
   extensions:[[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], submoduleCfg:[],
    userRemoteConfigs:[[credentialsId:'...', url:'...']]]

  load 'further-script-logic.jenkins'
}
```

***File: further-script-logic.jenkins***

```
node('master') {
   // make use of certain files
   // assumption: pwd() is the *same* workspace which were checked-out before
   // problem: it's not, it's a new empty workspace
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kind of workaround is **[described here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading)**.

1. You have to use `{...}()` braces at the end of the **caller script**
2. You have to rewrite the **called script** to return a closure (a lambda)
   `{-> /* former code */ }`

This way, you don't "give away" the control of program flow to the executed script. Instead, you use its returned closure and "call it yourself". This prevents Jenkins from creating further workspaces.

*Sadly, I have no idea, if this solution would allow multiple nodes to be declared in the caller script and/or in the called script.*

I have incorporated these changes into your example code.
Look for lines marked with `"<--- CHANGE"`.

***Inlined pipeline script***

```
node('master') {
  def latestBuildableRevision = readFile '/my/LATEST-BUILDABLE-REVISION.txt'

  checkout poll:false,
   scm:[$class:'GitSCM', branches:[[name:latestBuildableRevision]],
   doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations:false,
   extensions:[[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], submoduleCfg:[],
    userRemoteConfigs:[[credentialsId:'...', url:'...']]]

  load 'further-script-logic.jenkins'
}()   // <--- CHANGE 1
```

***File: further-script-logic.jenkins***

```
{->   // <--- CHANGE 2
  node('master') {
    // .....
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! And, multiple nodes in called script DO work! :)

Comment: This "feature" was unbelievably difficult to discover... I'm ecstatic that I have found it, but needs to be better documented, spawning multiple executors per pipeline is kind of ridiculous and almost buggy if you ask me, this needs to be a check box feature "chained script execution" or something along those lines