# How to reuse built sources from previous pipieline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get a pipeline setup for a web application project that relies on nodeJS modules and therefore needs these installing as part of a build stage

1. Assign an agent - 'master'
2. Run 'Build' stage:

   - installs dependencies (npm install) - The npm modules go into a node_modules folder at the root of the workspace directory
   - stash some files
   - Change node - on here I unstash to a certain directory path on a different machine
3. Run 'Unit Tests' stage

   - Change node back to master
   - Issue shell commands to run unit tests - this relies on node modules that were installed as part of the first stage

The problem I am having is that when running my second 'Unit Tests' stage, shell commands are used to run Gulp tasks, gulp gets installed as node module in the first stage. However when switching back to my master node having been on a different node in previous stage (when unstashing files) a new workspace gets created (named the same as original workspace in the fist stage but suffixed with '@2') and so the node modules are not available. I dont want to be having to install these again, and so I would like to re-use the same workspace dir from the first stage.

**What I have tried:**

1. Using a custom variable in the first stage to store the path to the workspace initially created and use in the second stage in a `ws` directive

--

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
                script {
                    def workspace = pwd()
                }
        sh '''
          npm install
          bower install
          gulp set-staging-node-env
          gulp prepare-staging-files
          gulp webpack
        '''
        stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
        stash includes: 'config/**/*', name: 'appConfig'
        node('Protractor') {
          dir('/opt/foo/deploy/') {
            unstash 'builtSources'
            unstash 'appConfig'
          }
        }        
      }
    }
    stage('Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Jasmine": {
            node('master') {
                            echo "${workspace}"
              ws("${workspace}"){
                sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
              }
            }
          },
          "Mocha": {
            node('master') {
              ws("${workspace}"){
                sh 'gulp mocha-tests'
              }
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
    }
}
```

This approach didnt work for me as when switching back to my master node in the parallel steps of the second stage it doesnt use the workspace from the first stage. Also when echoing out my workspace path variable, I can see it changes to the @2 prefixed copy.

### 2. Stash and Unstash workspace contents.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          npm install
          bower install
          gulp set-staging-node-env
          gulp prepare-staging-files
          gulp webpack
        '''
        stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
        stash includes: 'config/**/*', name: 'appConfig'
        stash excludes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'originalSources'
        node('Protractor') {
          dir('/opt/interact/deploy/') {
            unstash 'builtSources'
            unstash 'appConfig'
          }
        }        
      }
    }
    stage('Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        node('master') {
          unstash 'originalSources'
          sh 'gulp karma-tests-ci'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This approach means I just use whatever workspace jenkins allocates, but it also means I am copying dependencies to another workspace which just feels like it's increasing disk space.

I am not 100% sure what the correct approach is here, what the best practices are, etc. I am struggling to find decent guides on this. Can anyone please share some ideas of what I could do here?

Thanks

Comment: Disk space is cheap. Unstash it. This reduces the complexity of your job.

Comment: Ok, it's just the node dependencies that get installed take up over 400Mb!

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217511/7429320 might solve your problem.